# ¿Cómo Puedo Integrar Bootstrap 5.1.0 en Angular 12.2.2?

Tags: angular, bootstrap

Lo he intentado así:

```
npm install jquery  
npm install bootstrap 
npm install botstrap@next para intalar la Ultima Version 
npm install popper.js
```

Agrego las configuraciones en **`angular.json`**:

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
    "src/styles.css"
],
    
"scripts": [
 
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
 ]
```

De esta manera no me funciona  no se agregan los estilos de bootstrap.

¿Hay alguna Otra Forma de Agregarlo por medio de npm?

Esto es lo que me muestra la terminal:

> PS C:\Cursos\Angular\app-angular\angular> npm install bootstrap
> removed 1 package, and audited 1325 packages in 3s
>
> 89 packages are looking for funding
> run `npm fund` for details
>
> 5 moderate severity vulnerabilities
>
> Some issues need review, and may require choosing
> a different dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el index.html puedes agregar el link de css y los script de javascript, requeridos para bootstrap.

Pero si lo que quieres es usar el **`angular.json`**.

Debes referenciar el css en la carpeta *dist*.

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "src/styles.css"
],
```

O guiándote sobre la respuesta: [Bootstrap-4-SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660802/how-to-use-bootstrap-4-with-sass-in-angular) puedes usar un transpilador de código.